# Cannot access nested object values from component.html

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic4

Fellow geeks, I have a nested JSON object returned by an API, the obj is like:

```
profile : {
    title:"Mr",
    personalInfo:{
       fullNames: "John Doe",
       id: "569"
   }
   Address:{
    line1:"addd one",
    line2:"addd two" 
   }
}
```

my HTML component:

`<ion-input placeholder="Full Names" [(ngModel)]="profile.personalInfo.fullNames"  ></ion-input>`

when compiling the code, i run into a error that says  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'personalInfo' of undefined`

But when i access the *title* property from my HTML component which is not nested, it works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

That JSON is malformed, did you check that? You missed a "," before address key

```
{
  "title": "Mr",
  "personalInfo": {
    "fullNames": "John Doe",
    "id": "569"
  },
  "Address": {
    "line1": "addd one",
    "line2": "addd two"
  }
}
```

Comment: Makes no difference. Even when i trying to perform a console.log(profile.personalInfo.fullNames), it consoles it perfectly, problem comes when binding it to HTML

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing this response in any global variable that is access by HTML. It seems you are not storing it anywhere otherwise your binding would be shown as below.

```
<ion-input placeholder="Full Names" [(ngModel)]="response.profile.personalInfo.fullNames"  ></ion-input>
```

Store your response into global variable call response and access it into HTML.

Comment: I did store everything in a global object, and for some reason, I need to give my global object initial value of null and then it worked

Comment: Yes correct. You may also try using ? before accessing value. response?.profile?.personalInfo?.fullNames it will not throw error at least if its null or undefined.